# asp.net webhook - debugger does not break

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webhooks

I've created a web hook application, and I believe I have configured it properly.  I have published it out to Azure as a web app, and invoked the debugger from Visual Studio on my desktop.  I then created this breakpoint, just to test that I have connectivity and my test post can hit the debugger.  See screen shot....

[image: Screen shot after post succeeds]

I have configured the web config with the appropriate secret as well.

When I execute a test post (this is from Stripe) I can see the debug output (see below) is giving me back info on the post .../Stripe/Test .. and that the debugger has fired up and recognized the breakpoint (red dot filled in).  The Stripe testing tool, that sent out the test post, also shows the post was successful.

Yet the debugger does not break.  Is it because the method is a TASK?  Just wanted to get to first base here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Strip web hook has a filter on Evt_ID 000000000.  I was creating the web hook via their testing interface, as opposed to entering a test card number (Like 4242 4242 4242 4242).  There test interface always creates a web hook with evt_ID of 0000000 so the receiver is never instanciated.

I suggested they put in a debug message that states the request was received but filtered out due the event ID.  I think they are going to incorporate that in their next release.